# Upload file to virtual directory using Ajax call

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a CMS as MVC 4 project and one of the features is to **upload your photo**. The user chooses a photo from his hard drive, which triggers an ajax request to the UploadFile method on the controller. This should copy the photo to a virtual folder on the server. The problem is I don't really understand where the browser stores the file and sends it to the server, and what I am supposed to do on the controller.

This is my code so far -

The view:

```
<input id="cng_pic_btn" type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" /></td>
```

JavaScript making the call to the server:

```
$('#cng_pic_btn').live('change', function () {

    custom_url = "/SideBar/UploadFile";
    return_msg = "file uploaded";

    var file_path = $('#cng_pic_btn').attr("value");
    alert(file_path);
    sendInfo = {
        upload_from: file_path
    }

    CreataAjaxRequest(custom_url, sendInfo, return_msg);

})
```

The conroller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void UploadFile(string upload_from)
    {
            string path = @"D:\Temp\";

            HttpPostedFileBase photo = Request.Files[upload_from];

            photo.SaveAs(path + photo.FileName);
    }
```

send ajax request:

```
function CreataAjaxRequest(custom_url, sendInfo, return_msg) {

    $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: custom_url, data: sendInfo })
                .success(function (html) {
                    $(".query-result").replaceWith(html);

                })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown your `CreataAjaxRequest` method but if you want to upload files using AJAX there are a couple of options:

- your client browser supports the [`HTML 5 File API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) in which case you could use the XmlHttpRequest2 object
- your client browser doesn't support the File API (Such as Internet Explorer) in which case you could use a file upload plugin such as [`Uploadify`](http://www.uploadify.com/) or [`Fine Uploader`](http://fineuploader.com/) which use techniques like hidden iframes or Flash movies for those kind of legacy browsers.

Here's an example of how you could upload a file using the HTML 5 File API:

```
function CreataAjaxRequest(custom_url, sendInfo, return_msg) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fd = new FormData();
    xhr.open('POST', custom_url, true);
    var file = document.getElementById('cng_pic_btn').files[0];;
    fd.append('myFile', file);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            $('.query-result').replaceWith(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

and then on your server:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase myFile)
{
    var path = string path = @"D:\Temp\";
    myFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, myFile.FileName));

    return PartialView();
}
```

Also notice that your controller action needs to return a `PartialView`  if you want to use the `$('.query-result').replaceWith(xhr.responseText);` method in your AJAX callback, otherwise what are you replacing with?

Comment: i cant send the file to my exsitin js function function CreataAjaxRequest() and from there to the server ?

Comment: Did you read my answer? You cannot upload files using standard AJAX. You have 2 possibilities. Please read my answer once again to discover them. The first is to use the [`HTML5 File API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) (if your client browser supports it) and the second is to use a file upload plugin such as Uploadify or Fine Uploader.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example using the HTML 5 File API.